# Force sphinx autosummary to display the first line after the heading in module docstrings in modules' summary table

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, autosummary

For classes/functions, `sphinx`'s `autosummary` extension can generate a nice table summarizing the list of available classes/functions in a particular module, such that the first column consists a list of these items, and the second column consists of the first line taken from class/function docstrings as description (see below).

---

[image]

---

Likewise, if I have a module that itself contains several submodules, `autosummary` can also generate a similar summary table (see below).

---

[image]

---

But, as you can see, the description (i.e., the second column) in this case is simply the module's heading. For instance, in this example, the `solvers.py` module looks like:

```py
"""
Solvers
=======
Brief description of 'Solvers'!
"""
...
```

My question is: how can I tell `sphinx.autosummary` to display the first line (after the heading) from the module's docstrings as the description in the summary table? For instance, in this case, I'd want `autosummary` to display "Brief description of 'Solvers'!" in the second column for `solvers` module.

Many thanks!

Comment: @john-hen That's true, I basically want the first line after the heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I've encountered the same issue and (in case someone's still interested), solved it.
I created a simple solution for [python library function patching](https://gist.github.com/pseusys/43fc4ffbae0dcb85152c2e7a7f2c75df).
This solution can be used to patch this (and some other) Sphinx functions.

For this example the patching code will be:

```py
from sphinx.ext.autosummary import extract_summary
from patcher import wrap_source_function


def extract_summary_wrapper(func):
    return lambda doc, document: func(doc, document).split("\n\n")[-1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wrap_source_function(extract_summary, extract_summary_wrapper)
```

The patcher is the `patcher` [file from the gist](https://gist.github.com/pseusys/43fc4ffbae0dcb85152c2e7a7f2c75df#file-patcher-py).

> **NB!** This code snippet should be executed at least once (but can be executed each time) before `sphinx-build` command!

Cheers!